# What are the embedded web server libraries that I can use for Windows RT app?

Tags: windows-runtime, nanohttpd, cocoahttpserver

For android and iOS, I can use nanohttpd and cocoahttpserver respectively but I cannot seem to find one for WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick search, I guess you may interest in this lib.

[HttpServerWinRT](https://github.com/alfonsogarciacaro/HttpServerWinRT)